# perl installation directory specification

Tags: perl

I have perl 5.10.1 on my server but I need a higher version of perl than that. I do not have privileges to modify this version so I installed the latest one on my home directory. How do I specify unix to preferentially use the newer version?

Comment: Not a problem I've ever done, but you might find an answer by searching here for [perlbrew](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5Dperlbrew)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/). This is a tool to install and manage multiple Perl installations in your home directory. You can switch between which one is active.

Follow the instructions on their page to install perlbrew, and then install the latest stable Perl with...

```
perlbrew install stable
```

Then tell perlbrew that's the Perl you want to use with...

```
perlbrew switch stable
```

If you want to install more modules, use `cpanm` to install modules to the currently active perl.

```
cpanm Acme::Pony
```

---

If you don't want to use perlbrew, you need to mess with your PATH environment variable. This is a list of directories your shell will search through when finding a program to run. You'd need to put `/path/to/where/you/installed/perl/bin` at the front. [More on this in this article](https://kb.iu.edu/d/acar).

I ***highly*** recommend you use perlbrew. It takes care of all this for you.